# Postgres: AFTER trigger seems to prevent update action

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I have a table that has a 'state' variable.  When the state is changed, an after update trigger fires.  The after update trigger checks the state variable.  When a particular state is reached, the trigger makes an entry in another table and then advances the state via an sql update.  For accountability, we have a way of monitoring the state changes (it is rather complicated, but works fine.  It replicates table entries into a history table, it is also driven by triggers)  So, the initial table contains:

```
Table dummy:
   version: 0
   state: draft
```

In the Java app, SQL will advance the state to 'waiting' and it will increment the version number by doing something like:

```
UPDATE dummy SET version = 1, state = 'waiting'
```

The After trigger is created by:

```
CREATE TRIGGER dummy_update AFTER UPDATE ON dummy FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE check_state();
```

check_state() is a python function.  It checks the value of TD[new][state],
and if TD[new][state] is 'waiting', an entry is made into the process_queue table, followed by an update to the dummy table, setting the state to 'in_queue' and adding 1 to the sequence.

Pseudo code looks something like:

```
def check_state() :
   if (TD["new"]["state"] == 'waiting') :
      insert into queue an entry for this row
      update dummy SET state = 'in_queue'
   return "OK"
```

So what happens is:

1. The initial insert is fine.
2. The update to the state is committed in a transaction, isolation level is  default. The After Trigger fires, the TD[new][state] is printed and it is 'waiting', as expected.
3. An entry is made in the queue by the stored procedure
4. An update is issued to advance the state

No errors are detected in the postgres log.  (logging levels set to debug1).  The dummy table only shows 2 records -- UNLESS we are stepping through the Java code with the debugger.

If it runs NOT in the debugger, we get 2 records in the output, showing states of draft and in_queue.  If we step through with the debugger, we get 3 records in the output, showing states of draft, waiting, and in_queue.  The latter being the desired result.

So:

Is there anything I can do in the AFTER trigger to assure that the record with the state of 'waiting' is written to the database tables?

I saw a small blurb in one of the posts suggesting that an After Update cannot be done on a table processed by the SQL acting on the same table.  IE, if an update is done on dummy (in this case), the AFTER SQL cannot also do an update on dummy.  Now I cannot find anything in the POSTGRES manuals (I am running 9.3.5) or in any of the posts which concretely say I cannot do this -- OR -- provide an alternate suggestion.

Thanks --

Roy

Comment: What does `check_state();` do? Please add the code of the trigger function.

Comment: 'def check_state(): id = TD["new"]["record_id"]

Comment: Cannot figure out how to format code.  Only thing missing is check to make sure an entry doesn't already exist in the queue.

Comment: `'def check_state(): id = TD["new"]["record_id"]` is not valid PL/pgSQL - please post the **whole** `create function`  code

Comment: Python trigger: 'def check_state() : id = TD["new"]["record_id"]; rs = plpy.execute("select * from queue where record_id = 'id');  if (rs.nrows() == 0) insert into queue (record_id) values ('id'); plpy.execute("update dummy set state='in_queue' where record_id = 'id');'  NOTE again:  I cannot format this properly; It is PYTHON only I added the semicolons because I can't format it.